# Programmatically scroll to section with PDFJS

Tags: pdf.js

I'd like to use PDFJS to load a PDF document, then allow programmatic scrolling to named sections within the document. I have the following:

```
<div id="pdfContainer" class="well well-sf-errors-review">
    <canvas id="pdfCanvas"></canvas>
</div>

PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(
    function(pdf) {
      pdf.getPage(1).then(
        function(page) {
          var desiredWidth = document.getElementById('pdfContainer').clientWidth;
          var viewport = page.getViewport(1);
          var scale = desiredWidth / viewport.width;
          var scaledViewport = page.getViewport(scale);
          var canvas = document.getElementById('pdfCanvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.height = 600;
          canvas.width = scaledViewport.width;
          var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: scaledViewport
          };
          page.render(renderContext);
        }
      );
    }
);
```

What I get from this is the first page of the 22-page document, with no scrolling (scrolling to the next page). I'd like to have continuous scrolling with the ability to jump to a named section. Any pointers would be appreciated as I don't find the website or the code as informative as I need to fully understand PDFJS. Thanks!

Comment: I got it to render all the pages at once, s that's good. What I still don't know how to do is to scroll to a named section.  I see that I can use getDestination() to retrieve some object that described the section, but I don't what the values within the object mean.

Comment: did you got any solution